# Hexagon packing algorithm

Tags: computational-geometry, packing

I'm trying to pack hexagons, within bigger hexagons, as shown here:

[image]

For this example, I have 5 "children" to put in my "father" hexagon.

Each time I've got too many children, I would like to reduce the size (divide by 3?) of the children, to store more of them, as shown on this image (ignore the bad position quality):

[image]

Have you ever worked on this kind of problem? Is there any algorithm I could use to determine for a given hexagon size, the position for each new hexagon?

I've seen a lot of these algorithms for circle packing, but nothing for hexagon packing.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have in mind some criteria of quality of packing? Also you are saying "too many children" - what does that mean exactly? In order to get a good answer you have to formulate a good question

Comment: What do you expect to be the major difference between a circle-packing algorithm and a hex-packing algorithm for this kind of problem?